# Is it possible to implement flip in Scala like it is implemented in Haskell?

Tags: scala, haskell

Is it possible to implement flip in Scala like it is implemented in Haskell?

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#flip

```
flip                    :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
flip f x y              =  f y x
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way, more closer to Haskell version:

```
scala> def flip[a, b, c]: (a => b => c) => b => a => c = f => x => y => f(y)(x)
flip: [a, b, c]=> (a => (b => c)) => (b => (a => c))

scala> val f: Int => Char => String = i => c => f"Int($i) and Char($c)"
f: Int => (Char => String) = <function1>

scala> val g = flip(f)
g: Char => (Int => String) = <function1>
```

Or this:

```
scala> def flip[a, b, c]: (a => b => c) => b => a => c = {
     |   case f => x => y => f(y)(x)
     | }
flip: [a, b, c]=> (a => (b => c)) => (b => (a => c))


scala> g('a')(100)
res0: String = Int(100) and Char(a)

scala> f(100)('a')
res1: String = Int(100) and Char(a)
```

Answer (score 8):

Well, this is a fairly literal translation:

```
def flip[A, B, C](f: A => B => C)(x: B)(y: A) = f(y)(x)
```

Now you can write the following:

```
scala> def append: String => String => String = a => a + _
append: String => (String => String)

scala> append("foo")("bar")
res0: String = foobar

scala> val flipped = flip(append) _
flipped: String => (String => String) = <function1>

scala> flipped("foo")("bar")
res1: String = barfoo
```

You could argue that the following is a little closer to the spirit of the Haskell version:

```
def flip[A, B, C](f: A => B => C): B => A => C = x => y => f(y)(x)
```

Now you don't have to eta-expand the partially-applied method:

```
scala> val flipped = flip(append)
flipped: String => (String => String) = <function1>

scala> flipped("foo")("bar")
res2: String = barfoo
```

So you've got a couple of choices. It's not really clear that one is more like the Haskell implementation, but given the distinction that Scala makes between methods and functions they're both pretty close.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insightful answer Travis!